# ITMS-90078: Missing Push Notification Entitlement

Tags: ios, xcode, livecode

I created and submitted my iOS app to App Store Connect. But after submitting the build I got this email

*We identified one or more issues with a recent delivery for your app, "HIITimer Interval Workout" 1.0.1 (1). Your delivery was successful, but you may wish to correct the following issues in your next delivery:
ITMS-90078: Missing Push Notification Entitlement - Your app appears to register with the Apple Push Notification service, but the app signature's entitlements do not include the "aps-environment" entitlement. If your app uses the Apple Push Notification service, make sure your App ID is enabled for Push Notification in the Provisioning Portal, and resubmit after signing your app with a Distribution provisioning profile that includes the "aps-environment" entitlement. Xcode does not automatically copy the aps-environment entitlement from provisioning profiles at build time. This behavior is intentional. To use this entitlement, either enable Push Notifications in the project editor's Capabilities pane, or manually add the entitlement to your entitlements file. For more information, see https://developer.apple.com/library/con ... 94-CH6-SW1.
After you’ve corrected the issues, you can upload a new binary to App Store Connect.*

When I tried to research this problem on forums etc. I see some people have said it's just a warning that can be ignored but on the App Store Connect website it says "Invalid Binary" in red. I tried to click "Submit for Review" again but I got the same email. Is there any chance it's going to get sent through if I don't do anything?

On the developer.apple.com end in the Identifier for my app's Capabilities I unticked Push notifications and created a new distribution provisioning profile and resubmitted but this did not fix it.
In the Standalone App Settings for LC, I do not see any options for Push Notifications. And I don't think I've created any in my app.

Mac Catalina Version 10.15.3.
iPhone X IOS 13.3.1
LiveCode 9.6.0 (dp3)
Xcode 10.1 & 11.3 placed in the iOS SDKs

Comment: Go developer portal and disable push notification service for your app. OR integrate push notification in your app. Also, update the certificates as well.

Comment: Initially in my Identifier the push notifications were enabled. After I got the email error. I went back and disabled them and created new provisioning profiles. But the same email error came again. When you say 'update certificates' do I need to delete and make new ones?

Comment: No just edit the previous certificates.

Comment: how do you edit a certificate in the developer.apple.com if you click a certificate the only options are to Revoke or Download.

Answer (score 0):

We just released a version that contains the fix. Please upgrade and re-link the RN sdk

**react-native unlink react-native-flurry-sdk && react-native link react-native-flurry-sdk**
and type n while being asked if you need to integrate Flurry Push. This will guarantee that push related code won't be linked to your project. Please let me know if the problem still occurs. Thank you very much for your feedback!